# Is there any way to make the php filesize() method work with unicode characters?

Tags: php, unicode, filesize

For business reasons we cannot upgrade to php7.1 which now has the support required. We were hoping for a quick fix which will prevent the renowned "filesize(): stat failed" error. I am trying to get the filesize of a file with japanese characters in its name. The files could be quite large so any sort of opening and reading the file is not ideal. Below are some of the methods I have already tried passing to filesize() as parameters

I am using PHP version 5.6.30.

```
html_entities_decode($file, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8")

mb_convert_encoding($file, 'ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8')

iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1', $file)

urlencode($file)
```

Ideally it would return the size of the file as normal, I have been unsuccessful in making it work. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Changing the filename will just end up with it not finding it, a workaround is to hash the file on save, then use its hash as the filename, no issues with name and bonus of no dupe files.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone In our case this change would be on our central file generation process, we were hoping to avoid this. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Which OS? Which filesystem? You may want to use a symlink (unix/mac) or maybe check the files in the directory, and get the filename from there (filtering out the unwanted files).